# Controlling html dynamically inserted by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamically-generated

I generate a professional card HTML with JavaScript:

```
var professionalsCards = '';
$.each(professionalsData, function(i, item)
{
    professionalsCards += '<div class="col-md-3 professional_list_card">';
    professionalsCards += '<a href="#" onclick="showProfessionalDetails()">';
    professionalsCards += '<div class = "panel panel-default professional_list_panel">';
    professionalsCards += '<img src="'+websiteTPL+'images/user-without-avatar-400x400.jpg" height="75px" width="75px" alt="..." class="img-circle center-block" />';
    professionalsCards += '<h4 class="text-center">'+item.fullname+'</h4>';
    professionalsCards += '<input type="hidden" id="professional_uuid" name="professional_uuid" value="teste" />';
    professionalsCards += '</div></a></div>';
});

$("div#professionals_list").html(professionalsCards);
```

When i Populate it with HTML Directly the click function of jQuery work fine:

```
$(".professional_list_card").click(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var professional_uuid = jQuery(this).find("input:hidden");
    alert(professional_uuid.val());
});
```

But, when i insert the HTML with JavaScript the function click of jQuery not work.
Then i tried make a function and use onclick, not work too:

```
function showProfessionalDetails()
{
    var professional_uuid = jQuery(this).find("input:hidden");
    alert(professional_uuid.val());
}
```

How i control the HTML inserted with JavaScript? Click and Other Events?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to delegate the `click` event to a DOM element.

```
$("document").on("click", ".professional_list_card").click(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var professional_uuid = jQuery(this).find("input:hidden");
    alert(professional_uuid.val());
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: I tried your code, not work too...

Comment: I have no HTML to test with.

Comment: The object does not support the 'apply' property or method